# finding value of integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} (\cos x)^{2011} \sin (2013 x) dx $$

The value is given to be $\frac{1}{2012}$. I am while solving using by parts, but one term is remaining like $\frac{1}{2}$, then $\frac{1}{3},$ and so on. Kindly help.

what i am stuck at is following.

$$I(m,n) =\int_0^{\pi/2} (\cos x)^{m} \sin (n x) dx $$
$$I(m,n)= \frac {1}{m+n} + \frac{m}{m+n}I(m-1,n-1)$$
after deriving this i am not able to proceed further

Comment: why downvoting?

Comment: In this case, reasons for the down- and closevotes would be helpful. I do not see one.

Comment: What's meant by stuck?  You can not derive that or don't know how to utilize that

Comment: i have reached till this step. i am able to proceed further to answer which is 1/2011

Comment: This double recurrence relationship looks a deadend. I have found the general formula $$\int_0^{\pi/2} (\cos x)^{\nu-2} \sin (\nu x) dx=\dfrac{1}{\nu-1} $$ in a book. It can help to buid a more sympathetic recurrence...

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$n=m+2\implies$  $$I_{(m,m+2)}=\dfrac1{2m+2}+\dfrac m{2m+2}I_{(m-1,m+1)}$$

$I_{(0,2)}=1$

$m=1\implies$  $$I_{(1,3)}=\dfrac14+\dfrac14I_{(0,2)}=\dfrac12$$

$m=2\implies$  $$I_{(2,4)}=\dfrac16+\dfrac13I_{(1,3)}=\dfrac13$$

Use induction for $I_{(m-1,m+1)}=\dfrac2{m-1+m+1}$

Comment: why did you think to replace n= m+2 ? is it because of powers stated? can we solve for any difference?

Comment: @maveric, Yes because of the difference in powers.

Comment: could you ellaborate on induction ?

Comment: @If $I_{(m-1,m+1)}=\dfrac1m;$ hold true for $m=n$ Establish the same for $m=n+1$

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
I(m,n)
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^m(x)\sin(nx)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{m+1}(x)\sin((n-1)x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^m(x)\cos((n-1)x)\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=I(m+1,n-1)-\frac1{m+1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos((n-1)x)\,\mathrm{d}\cos^{m+1}(x)\tag3\\
&=I(m+1,n-1)+\frac1{m+1}-\frac{n-1}{m+1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{m+1}(x)\sin((n-1)x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag4\\
&=\frac{m-n+2}{m+1}\,I(m+1,n-1)+\frac1{m+1}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: define $I(m,n)$
$(2)$: $\sin(nx)=\sin((n-1)x)\cos(x)+\cos((n-1)x)\sin(x)$
$(3)$: prepare to integrate by parts
$(4)$: integrate by parts
$(5)$: simplify

Plug in $m=2011$ and $n=2013$ and see what happens.

However, this gives the answer $\frac1{2012}$, which is confirmed by Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

**Without reduction formula**
$$\int(\cos x)^{n-1} \sin ((n+1) x) d x =-\frac{\cos (n x)(\cos x)^n}{n}+C$$
Proof:
$\displaystyle \begin{aligned} \int(\cos x)^{n-1} \sin ((n+1) x) d x = & \int[\sin (n x) \cos x+\sin x \cos (n x)](\cos x)^{n-1} dx\\= & \int \sin (nx) (\cos x) ^{n}  d x+\int \sin x \cos (n x) (\cos x)^{n-1} d x \\= & \int \sin (n x) (\cos x)^{n} d x-\frac{1}{n} \int \cos (nx) d(\cos x)^{n} \\= & \int \sin (n x)( \cos x) ^{n} d x-\frac{\cos (n x)(\cos x)^{n}}{n} -\int \sin (nx)(\cos x)^{n} d x\\=& -\frac{\cos (n x)(\cos x)^{n}}{n}+C\end{aligned}\tag*{} $
Putting $n=2012$ yields

$$\displaystyle \boxed{ \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\cos x\right)^{2011} \sin (2013  x) d x =-\left[\frac{\cos (2012x)(\cos x)^{2012}}{2012}\right]_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}}=\frac{1}{2012}  }\tag*{} $$